# SSIS complains for not finding destination

Tags: ssis

In my Control Flow, I have a File System Task that copies an excel template file to a destination folder. The next in the chain is a Data Flow Task. It fills Excel Destination File (copied previously) from OLE DB Source. But I cannot start executing my package, as I get a validation error:

Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [38]]: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

I believe the validation is not finding the Excel file, as it does not exist in the destination folder until it is copied there from elsewhere. (It does work if I manually place the file into the destination folder).

What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent failing validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DelayValidation` property of the data flow task to `True`. By default it is set to False. When it is set to False it checks for the files existence before the component executes. After being changed to True the component will not check for the file until it is executed.

[image]